# How to pass a parameter into the constructor without import using MEF?

Tags: c#, export, prism, mef, factory

I'm working with MEF. And I was watching the demo called MVVM RI from PRISM, and a part of the program has this code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Factory class to create a question view model for a given question object.
    /// </summary>
    private static class QuestionViewModelFactory
    {
        private static Dictionary<Type, Func<Question, QuestionViewModel>> maps = new Dictionary<Type, Func<Question, QuestionViewModel>>()
        {
            { typeof(OpenQuestion), (q) => new OpenQuestionViewModel((OpenQuestion)q) },
            { typeof(MultipleSelectionQuestion), (q) => new MultipleSelectionQuestionViewModel((MultipleSelectionQuestion)q) },
            { typeof(NumericQuestion), (q) => new NumericQuestionViewModel((NumericQuestion)q) }
        };

        public static QuestionViewModel GetViewModelForQuestion(Question question)
        {
            Func<Question, QuestionViewModel> viewModelInstanceFactory = null;
            if (maps.TryGetValue(question.GetType(), out viewModelInstanceFactory))
            {
                return viewModelInstanceFactory(question);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Could not locate a view model for question type");
            }
        }
    }

    // Note that each class derived QuestionViewModel needs a constructor parameter to be created.
public abstract class QuestionViewModel : NotificationObject 
{ 
    protected QuestionViewModel() { ... } 
} 

public abstract class QuestionViewModel<T> : QuestionViewModel 
    where T : Question 
{ 
    protected QuestionViewModel(T question) { ... } 
}
```

In my software, I need this functionality, but now I'd like to do by discovery.

At the beginning, I was thinking to create a custom export to store only `QuestionViewModel` and to store as `contractName` the question type model. Check this.

```
[MetadataAttribute]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ExportViewModelForProblemAttribute : ExportAttribute
{
    public ExportViewModelForProblemAttribute(Type viewModelType, Type questionType)
        : base(questionType.ToString(), typeof(QuestionViewModel))
    {
    }
}
```

But then I said, how can I pass the the object by the constructor? The idea is to pass the object `q` without using Import. But I got lost at this part.

```
public class ProblemViewModelFactory
{
    private readonly CompositionContainer container;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ProblemViewModelFactory(CompositionContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public QuestionViewModelFactory GetQuestionViewModelFactory(Question question)
    {
        // what can I do to return the correspond view model with the question inside?
    }
}
```

What can I do to implement this mapping and pass the argument?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With the Silverlight variant of MEF, we can include a type called the `ExportFactory<T, TMetadata>`. What this type does, is spin up a new instance of the type each time we call `CreateExport()` on it, but it also includes some additional information (metadata) about the part.

Now, what you are currently doing is exporting your question view models using the question name as the contract name. This won't make it easy to get instances of all `QuestionViewModel` types, so rather than that, you should continue to export as `QuestionViewModel` and append some metadata to the type, so in this case, you need a name property, so we can define our metadata contract as:

```
public interface INameMetadata
{
  string Name { get; }
}
```

Now, let's make a modification to the export attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
[MetadataAttribute]
public class ExportQuestionAttribute : ExportAttribute, INameMetadata
{
  public ExportQuestionAttribute(string name)
    : base(typeof(QuestionViewModel))
  {
    this.Name = name;
  }

  public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

I've changed the export attribute type to call the base constructor with only the `type` argument, and instead, store the value of `name` in a property `Name`. You don't actually need to decorate your export attribute with our metadata contract `INameMetadata`, but I prefer to as it ensures that when I am exporting, I get the compile time checking that I am providing all the required metadata.

Next, we can make a modification to our consumer type:

```
[Export]
public class ProblemViewModelFactory
{
  private readonly IEnumerable<ExportFactory<Question, INameMetadata>> _questionFactories;

  [ImportingConstructor]
  public ProblemViewModelFactory(
    [ImportMany] IEnumerable<ExportFactory<Question, INameMetadata>> questionFactories)
  {
    if (questionFactories == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("questionFactories");

    _questionFactories = questionFactories;
  }

  public QuestionViewModel GetQuestionViewModel(string name)
  {
    return _questionFactories
      // Get matching question factories
      .Where(q => q.Metadata.Name == name)
      // Select the exported value
      .Select(q => q.CreateExport().Value)
      // First or default - what if the question doesn't exist?
      .FirstOrDefault();
  }
}
```

Now, we've modified this part in a couple of ways.

First, we only accept an instance of an `IEnumerable<ExportFactory<QuestionViewModel, INameMetata>>`, which is our collection of part factories. This should contain factories for every type of question that has been exported. The import part is the `GetQuestionViewModel` method (which I am assuming you wanted to return `QuestionViewModel`, not `QuestionViewModelFactory`). The `ExportFactory` type does the work of spinning up a new instance, and because it is of a type `ExportFactory<QuestionViewModel, INameMetadata>`, it has a `Metadata` property that is of type `INameMetadata` that we can query before we create our part.

The last method will query the set of available factories, checking the `Name` property of each `INameMetadata` instance, and returning that question which matches, or `null` if one cannot be found. It will also ignore multiple questions with the same name, and select only the first (this design decision will be up to you).

I hope that points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I guess I'm not understanding, how the QuestionViewModel will have the Question object parameter? It's a little bit confusing for me the ExportFactory and Metadata tags yet.